# How do I properly add a prefix (or suffix) to databinding in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

How do I databind a single TextBlock to say "Hi, Jeremiah"?

```
<TextBlock Text="Hi, {Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Looking for an elegant solution.  What is out there?  I'm trying to stay away from writing a converter for each prefix/suffix combination.

Comment: Looks like your accepted answer may be WPF only - you might remove the Silverlight tag.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you've only got a single value you need to insert, you can use Binding's [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat) property. Note that this **requires .NET 3.5 SP1** (or .NET 3.0 SP2), so only use it if you can count on your production environment having the latest service pack.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay, StringFormat='Hi, {0}'}"/>
```

If you wanted to insert two or more different bound values, I usually just make a StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal" that contains multiple TextBlocks, for example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Good "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeOfDay}"/>
    <TextBlock Text=", "/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="!"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Make sure you've got the 3.5SP1 installed to use this.

Comment: @rmoore: Good catch. I've edited my answer to make that stand out.

Comment: For multiple bindings, you could also use StringFormat in a MultiBinding.      <TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
     <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{1},{0}">
      <Binding Path="Prop1" />
      <Binding Path="Prop2" />
     </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
   </TextBlock>

Comment: Holy crap... knowing about StringFormat earlier would have been amazing.

Comment: @rmoore: I haven't worked with MultiBinding to speak of, but I had the impression that it always required you to write your own MultiValueConverter -- that there weren't any useful MultiValueConverters that shipped with the framework. Can StringFormat replace that?

Comment: @Joe White Yup, check out the remarks and examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx

Comment: @rmoore Right there in the page I linked to... *smacks forehead* But wow. That is good to know!

Comment: In case you've torn your hair out over and over again because you keep forgetting, THIS DOESN'T WORK ON *<Label...>* ELEMENTS.  Labels are a different animal, bindings don't work the same.  See here for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206612/wpf-stringformat-on-label-content

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Hi, " />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Joe White's StringFormat solution is probably the way to go. I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: Greg, I think you have a typo. Your containing TextBlock should be a StackPanel, Orientation="Horizontal".  Nevertheless, you solved a problem for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you replace the inner <TextBlock> with <Run>, this example will work.

Answer (score 3):

correction(minor) to @Joe White's solution

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode OneWay, StringFormat='Hi {0}}'"/>
```

single quotes are required to apply stringformat successfully

worked for me :)