# WPF StringFormat on Label Content

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I want to format my string binding as `Amount is X` where `X` is a property bound to a label.

I've seen many examples but the following doesn't work:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=MaxLevelofInvestment, 
   StringFormat='Amount is {0}'}" />
```

I've also tried these combinations:

```
StringFormat=Amount is {0}
StringFormat='Amount is {}{0}'
StringFormat='Amount is \{0\}'
```

I even tried changing the binding property's datatype to `int`, `string`and `double`. Nothing seems to work. This is a very common use case but doesn't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that the `Label.Content` property is of type `Object`, and `Binding.StringFormat` is only used when binding to a property of type `String`.

What is happening is:

1. The `Binding` is boxing your `MaxLevelOfInvestment` value and storing it the `Label.Content` property as a boxed decimal value.
2. The Label control has a template that includes a `ContentPresenter`.
3. Since `ContentTemplate` is not set, `ContentPresenter` looks for a `DataTemplate` defined for the `Decimal` type.  When it finds none, it uses a default template.
4. The default template used by the `ContentPresenter` presents strings by using the label's `ContentStringFormat` property.

Two solutions are possible:

- Use Label.ContentStringFormat instead of Binding.StringFormat, or
- Use a String property such as TextBlock.Text instead of Label.Content

Here is how to use Label.ContentStringFormat:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=MaxLevelofInvestment}" ContentStringFormat="Amount is {0}" />
```

Here is how to use a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MaxLevelofInvestment, StringFormat='Amount is {0}'}" />
```

Note:  For simplicity I omitted one detail in the above explanation:  The `ContentPresenter` actually uses its own `Template` and `StringFormat` properties, but during loading these are automatically template-bound to the `ContentTemplate` and `ContentStringFormat` properties of the `Label`, so it seems as if the `ContentPresenter` is actually using the `Label`'s properties.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, now it makes sense. up to WPF team to make this neat for the future.

Comment: I like your answer, would you know how to use 2 params instead of just 1? Really struggling here (like TextBlock stringFormat can handle multiple when using triggers etc).

Comment: Why is it in this case you need to put **Path=** in front of your binding? normally i could just do `Content="{Binding MaxLevelofInvestment}"` and it works just fine...

Comment: For posterity: if you start a ContentStringFormat with a `{0}`, don't forget to put `{}` before it. So make it `ContentStringFormat="{}{0} some text here"`

Comment: Also for posterity, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7980937/120440 for the purpose of the `{}`-- it's baffling until you understand why.

Answer (score 6):

Make a universal `StringFormatConverter : IValueConverter`. Pass your format string as `ConverterParameter`.

```
Label Content="{Binding Amount, Converter={...myConverter}, ConverterParameter='Amount is {0}'"
```

Also, make `StringFormatMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter` when you need more than one object in format string, for instance, `Completed {0} tasks out of {1}`.

Comment: I like this. I can see the value of using both the pure `XAML` approach or the value converter.

Answer (score 4):

I just checked and for some reason it doesn't work with the `Label`, probably because it uses a `ContentPresenter` for the `Content` property internally. You can use a `TextBlock` instead and that will work. You could also put the `TextBlock` excerpt below in the content of a `Label` if you need to inherit styling, behaviour etc.

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MaxLevelofInvestment, StringFormat='Amount is \{0\}'} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a converter....

```
<myconverters:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>


<Label Content="{Binding Path=MaxLevelofInvestment, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter"} />


public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return String.Format("Amount is {0}", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is overkill.  I explain the cause of the problem and present two simple solutions in my answer.

Comment: I agree this hides usage, I've recently inherited a project where this approach was taken and would much prefer developers to use the build in StringFormat than roll their own.