# What do the {} brackets mean in the StringFormat section of a Binding syntax?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

In data-binding you can use multi-binding.. and with multi-binding you can combine properties such {}{0} {1}. My question is what mean the first {} ? I am not talking about {0} which is used to select which property to use..

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's the [markup extension {} escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx):

> The escape sequence ({}) is used so that an open brace ({) can be used as a literal character in XAML.

To elaborate: In XAML markup, `{` and `}` are special characters: For example, writing `{Binding}` creates a Binding object. You, however, want to set the property `StringFormat` to the *literal* value `{0} {1}`. Thus, you prefix your property value with `{}` to tell the parser: "The following braces are just braces and do not carry any special meaning."

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? In my XAML, I have quite a lot of entries like this one `<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}/{1}"><Binding Path ="MPNr"/><Binding Path ="Number"/></MultiBinding>`, and it fills in the values of `MPNr` and `Number`, without showing curly braces.

Comment: @Dominique: When I wrote *"The following braces are just braces and do not carry any special meaning"* I meant "...do not carry any special meaning **for the XAML parser**". You are right that they have a special meaning for MultiBinding's StringFormat property, but the XAML parser should ignore them and pass them through "as they are" to MultiBinding. The problem is that, by default, braces have a special meaning *both* in XAML *and* in format strings. As an analogy, it's like trying to show (raw) HTML code on a HTML page. You need to escape the tags.