# DisplayMemberPath concatenation

Tags: .net, wpf, combobox

I am trying to bind two values to a ComboBox display value, but I do not know how to do.

This way does not work:

```
cboRegion.DisplayMemberPath = "idregion" + "description";
```

Does anyone know how to do that in C#?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with `DisplayMemberPath`. You have the following alternatives:

- **Specify a DataTemplate**

  ```
  <ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
          <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}: {1}">
              <Binding Path="idregion"/>
              <Binding Path="description"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
  ```

  <sup>(If you are wondering about the empty braces in the StringFormat attribute, see: [What do the {} brackets mean in the StringFormat section of a Binding syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7980885/87698))</sup>
- **Add a property or field to your data source**. How to do that depends on your data source:

  If your combo box is bound to a DataTable, add a DataColumn and fill its values in a loop. Alternatively, change your SQL and add the concatenated value to your `SELECT` clause.

  If your combo box is bound to a POCO or entity framework object, add a property that returns the concatenation.

Comment: Adding a property to your object and setting the concatenated values there is a super easy way to go...

Comment: With IsEditable=true ItemTemplate will only work for dropdown, not for the selected value. Combobox will still call `SelectedValue.ToString()` and display type name if you didn't override it.

Answer (score 23):

You need to use a `DataTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cboRegion">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding idregion}" />
                <Run Text="{Binding description}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it in C#, not in XAML?

Comment: @Ztere0: You could create the DataTemplate in C# too, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/248362/how-do-i-build-a-datatemplate-in-c-sharp-code. Note, however, that the XAML code is easier and more readable in this case.

Comment: @Ztere0, yes, but it's not convenient at all... why would you want to do it in C#?

Comment: Thanks for that. WPF positively surprises me on a daily basis :-)

Comment: With IsEditable=true ItemTemplate will only work for dropdown, not for the selected value. Combobox will still call `SelectedValue.ToString()` and display type name if you didn't override it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view, concatenate the two fields, and then refer to the concatenated field name in your DisplayMemberPath property in c#, after referring to the new view in your itemssource property (and after updating your entity framework model)