# Combine text to String.Format

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I have this `StringFormat StringFormat={}{0:#,0}}` that represent decimal numbers and I want add text of my own after this number.

This is what I have tried (but it does not compile with the text inside the `StringFormat`)

```
Content="{Binding Path=(my:MyClass.MyStaticProperty),StringFormat={}{0:#,0}} My Text"

my:MyClass.MyStaticProperty is integer type.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552853/how-to-bind-multiple-values-to-a-single-wpf-textblock is it suitable for you?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't `StringFormat={}{0:#,0} Some text here}` work? - EDIT: Nevermind, it doesn't.

Comment: user @VMaleev: what about my binding ? i am using binding inside mt text property

Comment: You can of course write `StringFormat={}{0:#.0} Some Text`.

Comment: user @Clemens  this is not compile

Comment: `Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat={}{0:#.0} Some Text}"` compiles and runs well for me.

Comment: Please specify what exactly you expect. Is the after-decimal part of text bound or it's static text?

Comment: Please see my update, maybe this is related to my binding ?

Comment: `StringFormat` only works if the type of the target dependency property is `String`

Comment: improved grammar, added tag, removed language name from title and reworded to better explain problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use Label, Content cannot be formatted with StringFormat. Please view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206612/wpf-stringformat-on-label-content) topic.

Your solution is to use [ContentStringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static my:MyClass.MyStaticProperty}}"
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0:#.0} My Text"/>
```

Comment: compiler error: the character M is en expected at this position