# StringFormat inside a Label ToolTip

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to set a tooltip inside a label to a binding:

```
<Label Content="x"
 ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=date, StringFormat=Date: {0:G}}" />
```

However this doesn't work (i.e. I only get the date without the string "Date: " - e.g. "1/1/2015 15:38") apparently because the ToolTip type is object.
I've tried several remedies such as 1) putting the binding inside a TextBlock inside a tooltip inside a label.tooltip inside the label; 2) putting a TextBlock inside a label.tooltip with the binding (and several others);
All of which do not work.

Is there any simple way of achieving what I want? (I don't mind using converters as long as 1) no external library is involved 2) there is nothing in the code behind - I want all the display code to be in XAML)

Comment: And what is "_this" in your xaml? And if there is no code behind, what is "svm.date"?

Comment: @Spawn
_this is the current window, svm.date is just an object that has a date variable.

Comment: Can you show all problem code?

Comment: I think the `svm.date` code will help.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake copying. Is it better now?

Comment: @Spawn
`public Window1()
        {
            date = DateTime.Now;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public DateTime date { get; set; }`

Comment: Better now...But I still not knowing what is `svm`

Comment: @Kirenenko

Changed svm simply to date. See above comment for the origin of date.

Comment: Ok now, then it still printing the "1/1/2015 15:38" without the "Date:" part, or it does not print nothing now?

Comment: @Kirenenko
Still prints just the date without the "Date: " part.
XAML is         
`<Window Name="_this" Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="x" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=date, StringFormat=Date: {0:G} }" />
    </Grid>
</Window>`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that ToolTip is typed to be `object` and the StringFormat part of a binding is only used when the [dependency property is of type string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209539/8521).

It's easy to reproduce:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static system:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=Date: {0:g}}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static system:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=Date: {0:g}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The textblock will output the correct thing (`Date: ....`) while the label will just call `ToString()` on the DateTime.

---

To solve your problem, simply define the tooltip in the slightly more verbose way:

```
<Label Content="x">
    <Label.ToolTip>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static system:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat=Date: {0:g}}" />
    </Label.ToolTip>
</Label>
```

Or you can bind the tooltip to a property on your viewmodel which does the formatting for you:

```
public string MyTooltipString { get { return String.Format("Date: {0:g}", theDate); } }
```

And then:

```
<Label ToolTip="{Binding MyTooltipString}" />
```

Comment: I tried this: `<Label Content="x">
            <Label.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=date, StringFormat=Date: {0:g}}" />
            </Label.ToolTip>
        </Label>` and the tooltip is empty.

Comment: As for the other suggestion - I would prefer my code to be in XAML so that it's not hidden behind in the code (since it is an integral part of the display). If there is no other option then I will put the code in the codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Label Content="x"
ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=svm.date, StringFormat=Date: {0:G} }" />
```

**EDIT>>>>**

I've tested it and it works and prints the "Date:" string, **but only with dates**. Maybe the problem is that your svm.date is not a date.