# WPF Binding StringFormat doesn't change the output

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

I'm developing a WPF with C# and .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I have this number 1010 and I want to show it like this 1.010 (I'm Spanish).

To do it, I have modified XAML:

```
<Label x:Name="labelCounterCamera" Margin="5,2" 
Content="{Binding CounterCamera, StringFormat=N{0}}" />
```

But it shows the number without format: 1010.

`CounterCamera` is:

```
public uint CounterCamera
{
    get { return counterCamera; }

    set
    {
        if (!value.Equals(counterCamera))
        {
            counterCamera = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent("CounterCamera");
        }
    }
}
```

Why that StringFormat doesn't work? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: formatting of Label content requires another approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206612/wpf-stringformat-on-label-content

Comment: It seems `StringFormat` works only if the `TargetType` is of type `string`, here `Content` property is of type `object` I guess.

Comment: You need to escape string so: `StringFormat={}{0:N}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use ContentStringformat when using a Label

```
<Label x:Name="labelCounterCamera" Margin="5,2" 
   Content="{Binding CounterCamera}"
   ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the format string inside the placeholder token.

```
Content="{Binding CounterCamera, StringFormat={0:N}}"
```

`{0:N}` instead of `N{0}`

Comment: No, it doesn't compile.

Comment: You need to escape using StringFormat={}{0:N}

Comment: @apc Now, it compiles but I get no format.

Comment: Check the immediate window output for errors, this should would with a TextBlock however I'm not sure about Labels so see blindmeis answer