# MarkupExtension not working with Label?

Tags: xaml, string-formatting, markup-extensions

I don't understand why my MarkupExtension StringFormat does not work with labels but works perfectly with TextBlocks.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof (BindingExpression))]
public class Format : MarkupExtension
{
    #region Public Properties

    public BindingBase Binding { get; set; }

    public IValueConverter Converter { get; set; }

    public string StringFormat { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods and Operators

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.Binding.StringFormat = this.StringFormat;
        return this.Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{wpfApplication31:Format Binding={Binding Name}, StringFormat=X_{0}}" /> <!-- StringFormat WORKING -->
<Label Content="{wpfApplication31:Format Binding={Binding Name}, StringFormat=X_{0}}" /> <!-- StringFormat NOT WORKING -->
```

The property 'Name' is a simple string.

I think it's related to the fact that Label is a more complex object than TextBlock but I still don't understand why the StringFormat is not applied.

If anybody can help.
Thx

Comment: I know I can achieve the StringFormat in the Binding but as I said, it's a simplified version and I need the StringFormat in the MarkupExtension.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209539/10352740) :

> The reason this doesn't work is that the `Label.Content` property is of type `Object`, and `Binding.StringFormat` is only used when binding to a property of type `String`.

And to make it work you'd need to adapt the behaviour of your `MarkupExtension` to make it set the `Label.ContentStringFormat` when it's used for the `Label.Content` property. You can use the `IServiceProvider` that you recieve as the first parameter of the `ProvideValue` method.