# WPF binding: concatenate string with integer number using stringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, label

I have a WPF label which is bound to a property in the view model:

```
  <Label x:Name="Results" Content="{Binding Matching, String.Format='Results: {0}'}">
```

I am trying to concatenate the string with the number returned by the property, for example, if Matching returns 5 I would like to display:

Results: 5

but it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF StringFormat on Label Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206612/wpf-stringformat-on-label-content)

Comment: Use a TextBlock with Run, `<TextBlock><Run Text="Results: "/><Run Text="{Binding Matching}"/></TextBlock>`