# DataGridRow header binding with StringFormat

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

tl;dr I have a DataGrid, and I'm binding the row headers. However, I can't get this to work with the `StringFormat` property on the binding.

I've got a WPF DataGrid set up like this:

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="All"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Lane, StringFormat=Lane {0:0}}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value1}" Header="Value 1" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value2}" Header="Value 2" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value3}" Header="Value 3" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value4}" Header="Value 4" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But no matter what I do, I can't get the `StringFormat` property to work properly on the `DataGridRow` header. All it shows is the number that I've bound, and not the format text. But, if I put the same format string on a `TextBlock`, it works perfectly.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Lane, StringFormat=Lane {0:0}}"/>
```

Does anyone know why the `StringFormat` property isn't used properly? Is there a way I can get the behaviour I want?

---

Edit: This is what the Lane property looks like.

```
public int Lane {
    get { return lane; }
    set {
        lane = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try StringFormat={} Lane {0:0} ?

Comment: @Marsh that doesn't work either :(

Comment: What is `Lane`?

Comment: It's an integer property @NetMage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It has to do with the fact that the `Header` property is an object, not a string, and therefore the `StringFormat` property is not used (for more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4206612/8718143)). In order to fix this, I needed to set the data template for the row. The following style achieves what I want.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Lane}"/>
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type sys:String}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=Lane {0:0}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

P.S. Shout out to Marsh for suggesting setting the control template, which made me look at the default control template, without which my attempts to Google this would have remained fruitless.

---

**Edit:** Another way to handle this is using the `ContentStringFormat` property on `DataGridRowHeader`. So, keep the header binding in the `RowStyle`, and add the following `RowHeaderStyle`.

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="Lane {0:0}"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Comment: The `ContentStringFormat` referenced in your link wouldn't work?

Comment: @NetMage As far as I can tell, that's not a property of DataGridRow.... but it IS a property on DataGridRowHeader. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I made a little test project and this works for me.

As noted the control template will overwrite styles.

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lane, StringFormat=Lane {0:0}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
```

Using a data template for the ContentTemplate and binding to the correct source will preserve the styles.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=Item.Lane, StringFormat=Lane {0:0}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm probably going to go with one of my solutions for simplicity's sake, but that's another good way of handling it. Thank you.