# WPF newbie binding questions

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I just implemented a click counter in WPF, and I'm curious if there are better ways to do things.

Full code is here:
https://github.com/surferjeff/ClickCount/tree/main/WpfCounter

In the code behind, is it never possible to access properties on `DataContext` directly?  Must I keep another member another member around with the correct type?

Next, is there a way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged with fewer lines code?

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfCounter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ClickCount clickCount = new ClickCount();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = clickCount;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // DataContext.clickCount += 1;
            // Why does the commented line above fail to compile with the error?
            // Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'clickCount' and no accessible extension method 'clickCount' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ?)
            clickCount.Count += 1;
        }
    }

    class ClickCount : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        int _count = 0;
        public int Count {
            get => _count;
            set {
                _count = value;
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

In the .xaml, is there a way to combine the "Count: " text and the count value in a single Label?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfCounter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfCounter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="350">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <!-- None of the following work:
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="20">Count: {Binding Count}</Label>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10" FontSize="20">{Binding Count}</Label>
            -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,0,10" FontSize="20">Count:</Label>
                <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,10,10" FontSize="20" Content="{Binding Count}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Padding="10,5,10,5" Click="Button_Click">Click Me</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot assign a value like `DataContext.Count += 1`, since the `DataContext` is of type `object`, which does not implement the `Count` property even though the assigned object is of type `ClickCount`. I would recommend you to look into polymorphism in OOP. Instead of what you tried, you may cast the `DataContext` to the type `ClickCount` like this
`((ClickCount)DataContext).Count += 1`. You may find more on type casting here: [Casting and type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#type-conversion-exceptions-at-run-time).

But typically you want to achieve this behavior via Commands in MVVM. So, instead of the code you have shown you would create an implementation of the `ICommand` interface (often called a `RelayCommand`) which you would then put into the class `ClickCount` and bind the command to the `Command` property of the `Button` in XAML. For more information you may look here [MVVM - Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/may/mvvm-commands-relaycommands-and-eventtocommand).

In order to reduce the numbers of lines you may implement an abstract class which all the view-models (`DataContext`) would inherit from or rather you may use some Nugets which already implement this. I personally like the [Community MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/), which contains implementations of interfaces `INotifyPropertyChanged` (`ObservableObject` with the `SetProperty` method for invoking the `PropertyChanged` event) and `ICommand` (`RelayCommand`).

Lastly, you can use a single `Label` if you specify a `ContentStringFormat` in the `Label` like this: `<Label Content="{Binding Count}" ContentStringFormat="Count: {0}"/>`. Also mentioned here: [WPF StringFormat on Label Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4206612/wpf-stringformat-on-label-content)

Answer (score 1):

> In the code behind, is it never possible to access properties on DataContext directly?

No. Since the type of the `DataContext` property is `object`, you need to cast it.

The common approach is otherwise to set the `DataContext` property to an instance of a view model class (look up the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) design pattern) and perform any logic in this class but that's another story.

> Next, is there a way to implement INotifyPropertyChanged with fewer lines code?

You could use a source generator such as [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to dynamically inject code that raises the `PropertyChanged` event at compile time.

Then you can implement your `ClickCount` type like this:

```
public class ClickCount : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Count { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

> In the .xaml, is there a way to combine the "Count: " text and the count value in a single Label?

If you use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label`, you could use the `StringFormat` option:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Count, StringFormat={}Count: {0}}" />
```

`ContentStringFormat` works for a `Label` but you should generally use `TextBlocks` to display text:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Count}" ContentStringFormat="Count: {0}"/>
```